# Passing CSocket to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11

I'm writing multithreading server using `CSocket`. So, as usually, I have listening server socket, and need to create receiving socket for each connected client. To provide multiple clients handling, I want to create new `std::thread` for each client, `detach` it, and next handle this client inside thread function.

---

I'm trying to do like this:

```
int client_handler(CSocket receiver)
{
  return 1;
}

CSocket server;
BOOL created = server.Create(12345);
server.Listen();
while(true)
{
  CSocket receiver;
  if (server.Accept(receiver))
  {
     std::thread handler(client_handler, receiver);
  }

}
...
```

I got a compiler error at `std::thread` instantiation :

```
error C2664: 'std::tuple<int (__cdecl *)(CSocket),CSocket>::tuple(std::tuple<int (__cdecl *)(CSocket),CSocket> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__cdecl &)(CSocket)' to 'std::allocator_arg_t'
```

I've read `std::thread` docs, but still can't understand - why СSocket cannot be passed to?

Comment: MSDN is surprisingly silent on copy-constructability of `CSocket`. May be it is simply non-copy constructible?

Comment: @SergeyA `CSocket` is derived from `CObject`, which is indeed non-copyable. It's probably best to `Detach`, pass raw `SOCKET` to the thread, and `Attach` there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, and I take it, it is not movable either?

Comment: @SergeyA I haven't looked into that, but I'd be surprised if it were.

Comment: If it is really non-copyable you can also declare it with `new` and pass a pointer to `client_handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

You use a [`CSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb.aspx) object in the thread instantiation, passing it by value. The arguments for the callable passed to [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) shall be move or copy constructible.  Unfortunately, a `CSocket` is neither copiable nor movable, this is why you get the error.

**Solution:**

The alternative would be to pass the socket by reference. In this case you would have to wrap it with `std::ref()` in order to avoid that your thread receives a reference to a copy.  But you can't consider this alternative here, because `receiver` is an object with local storage.  It might be destroyed before the thread is finished, causing undefined behavior.

Two possibilities then:

1. have `receiver` as a member of your class, or at least ensure that it's available until the thread is finished. The reference approach would then become viable
2. create the CSocket dynamically, using a `shared_ptr` and passing this `shared_ptr` in the thread instantiation (and in the `client_handler()` ).

**Comments:**

While not strictly related to your current issue, note that in your snippet, you create `handler` as a local object to the `if`-bloc. So the object will get destroyed when you leave the bloc and without having joined the thread.  This will cause UB: you have to join or detach the thread before destroying the corresponding thread object.

So either you change the structure of your code to take this constraint into consideration and manage yourself the threads, or you consider using [`std::async()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) in case you just want to execute the reception code asynchronously.